# Bootstrap navbar won't collapse on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I've been trying for hours to get this working. Looked at several examples on starkoverflow. But I can't solve it. Some suggested that this should be added:

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

But I have no idea where to add it. I tried adding it to bootstrap.js but it didn't work. I'm a novice, trying to put up a first website by learning to piece together one. This is the website that I'm editing: [fotroviciliji.si](http://fotroviciliji.si). The bootstrap menu that appears on smaller devices won't close after a link has been clicked. I've looked at examples, even at those here that should be working, but don't. It stil doesn't close after clicking on a link in the menu. A user posted this fiddle of it supposedly working but when I try in Chrome, it just doesn't. The menu does not collapse after something has been selected. What am I doing wrong? This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/By6ym/4/) works but I'm too stupid to apply it to my website.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It may not have worked because you included it in bootstrap.js but not in bootstrap.min.js which seems to take over on small screen sizes like mobile phones. Include your code at the bottom of the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js files and the navbar should collapse after clicking/pressing a link to an internal anchor (whether you perform the action on a phone (bootstrap.min.js) or reduced window size on a tablet/desktop (bootstrap.js).

```
+function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('click', 'navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
            $(this).collapse('toggle');
        }
    });  
}(jQuery);
```

The above code worked for me. I retrieved lines 2-7 from another forum and I can't remember where. The premise, as far as I understand from searching the net, is that the internal links don't refresh the page (in a one page website, for example) and the navbar will only collapse when it arrives at a new page. The above javascript code was created to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've honesly been trying for a couple of hours. This is what works for me now, I added:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="scroll hidden" href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PONUDBA<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#ponudba"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Čili omake</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#paste"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Čili paste</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#vlozeni"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Vloženi čiliji</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#ostalo"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Ostalo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#cenik"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">CENIK</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#mesta"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">PRODAJNA MESTA</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#kontakt"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">KONTAKT</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a class="scroll" href="#obrazec">OBRAZEC</a></li> -->             
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

To each menu item. The menu now colapses back on it's own after something is selected.